# Why I get the problems with Visual Studio "2013" SDK samples?

Tags: visual-studio, sdk, vspackage

Visual Studio 2013 Premium Update 4; Visual Studio 2013 SDK installed.

[image]

I see the code sources are for older Visual Stuido version. It has a link to Visual Studio 2010 (instead of 2013) SDK Samples.zip file. I try compile its some projects but I get an exceptions... For example:

[image]

Other projects compiled successfully, but I read their instruction of running:

> **Running the Sample**
>
> To run this sample, copy both the
>   AlphaBlendToolbar.Addin file and the newly-built AlphaBlendToolbar.dll
>   file into your Visual Studio Addins directory (My Documents\Visual
>   Studio *20**10**\Addins*) and then open a new instance of Visual Studio
>   2010. Next, run the Tools | Add-in Manager menu command. Check the checkbox next to AlphaBlendToolbar and hit OK. You should see a new
>   toolbar with two command buttons on it. The interesting thing about
>   this sample is that the command button icons have alpha-transparency.

But VS 20**13** has not the **Addins** directory... Ok, I create it:

[image]

I compiled the sample of SDK:

[image]

but I don't see here the compiled DLL:

[image]

[image]

Why I have such problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The AddIns folder under the Documents folder is not created by default by VS when installed, so you need to create it by hand, as you have done
- Remove the folder C:\Users\developer\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\AddIns from the Options window, it is not required, the %VSMYDOCUMENTS%\AddIns folder takes care.
- .AddIn files can contain several  values to describe the target VS versions. The AlphaBlendToolbar.AddIn file of the sample only contains the VS 2010 target, you need to edit it and add the VS 2013 ("12.0") target:

<HostApplication>
   <Name>Microsoft Visual Studio</Name>
   <Version>12.0</Version>
</HostApplication>

- Notice that there are two .AddIn files, one in the Documents folder (for deployment) and other in your solution (for source control, etc.), ensure that you update both.
- FWIW, there is a VS 2013 SDK Samples: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsx/archive/2014/05/30/vs-2013-sdk-samples-released.aspx